# How to take user input inside an infinite loop

Tags: c, loops

I created a program which takes an integer From user and prints " hello welcome to c programming" but if user inputs a character, which scanf() cannot convert, then it will give an error message "please input integers only" and keep reading until the user inputs an integer. But the problem is that when I input a character then the program is not reading the input and running like an infinite loop. Here is my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    signed short a;
    while(!0) {
        printf("Input integers Only : ");
        if(scanf("%hd", &a) !=0) {
            printf("Hello\nWelcome To C programming\n");
            break;
        }
        else
            printf("\nERROR: please input integers only\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting that if user inputs a character, the program will give an warning message and again it will keep on reading until user inputs an integer.

Comment: Unrelated, but `while(!0)` is more idiomatically written as `while(1)`, `while(true)`, or `for( ; ; )`. Is there a specific reason behind using a `short signed` type? `scanf(3)` returns the number of conversions successfully performed, test against `1`. You need to remove the invalid input from before prompting for input again.

Answer (score 0):

When **scanf** fails to read the input stream based on the criteria, the pointer to the data is at the same location and the **scanf** for the next time tries to read data at the same location, thereby coming up with the infinite loop in your use case. It is necessary to **clear the buffer** before you read it for the next time or use **fscanf** or **sscanf** as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

**Non-numeric input not consumed**

When `if(scanf("%hd", &a) !=0) {` returns 0, the non-numeric input is not consumed.

As OP's code does not consume any of that, the same issue occurs in the next loop.

**End-of-file is not a successful read of an integer**

When `scanf("%hd", &a)` returns `EOF` due to end-of-file or a rare input error, `a` is not assigned a value.

---

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    signed short a;
    while (true) {
        printf("Input integers Only : ");
        int scan_count = scanf("%hd", &a);
        if (scan_count == 1) { 
            printf("Hello\nWelcome To C programming: %hd\n", a);
            break;
        } else if (scan_count == 0) {
            in ch = getchar(); // Remove at least 1 character
            printf("\nERROR: please input integers only, not '%c'\n", ch);
        } else {
            printf("End-of-file or input error detected.\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```